# the difference between AR(1) estimation and lagged endogenous variable estimation

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, lags

I'm very new to Time Series models. One of my biggest confusions is why estimation of Y with an AR(1) term is not the same thing as estimation of Y on a lagged value of Y. In other words, How are the following equations different from each other:
Y= Constant + AR(1)
Y= Constant + Y(-1)

Comment: Have a look at this blog post:   http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood would only differ if you treated the distribution of the first time point differently. If you don't, you'll get the same parameter estimates.

The R code below sets the `method=` argument of `arima()` to "conditional-sum-of-squares", which maximizes the same likelihood you would work with if you regressed $y_{2:100}$ on $y_{1:99}$.

```
y <- arima.sim(model = list(ar=.9), n = 100)
lag.y <- y[-100]
summary(lm(y[-1] ~ lag.y + 0))
arima(y, order = c(1,0,0), method = c("CSS"), include.mean = F)
```